# Through reflection acquisition method is affected by whether the receiver is a pointer

Tags: go

I used Go's reflection function to get the type of the method, but I found that the method I can get is related to whether the recipient is a pointer. Why is that?

When I ran the code below, I got the following result。

```
--- value interface ---
Test
--- pointer interface ---
Test
ToString
```

I don't understand how the result obtained by the Method method is related to whether the recipient is a pointer or not.

```
type User struct{}
type Admin struct{ User }

func (*User) ToString() {
    fmt.Println("tostring")
}

func (Admin) Test() {
    fmt.Println("test")
}
func main27() { 
    var u Admin
    methods := func(t reflect.Type) {
        for i, n := 0, t.NumMethod(); i < n; i++ {
            m := t.Method(i)
            fmt.Println(m.Name)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("--- value interface ---")
    methods(reflect.TypeOf(u)) 
    fmt.Println("--- pointer interface ---")
    methods(reflect.TypeOf(&u))
}
```

Comment: Because `*T` and `T` are two separate types and their [method sets](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) differ.

Comment: `ToString` is defined on the pointer, so if you don't have a pointer you don't have that method.